# PHP Redirect doesn't get executed?

Tags: php, sql, forms

I got a problem storing my form values. My goal is to submit my first form, save the values inside a variable, redirect to my second form and submit/store all form values inside my database(SQL).

HTML

```
<form action="process.php" class="form" method=POST name="firstform" onsubmit="return chkForm()">
      <label id="form_title">Bevor wir anfangen können, benötigen wir noch ein paar Informationen von Ihnen:</label>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <label for="name">Benutzername</label> 
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="">

      <label for="email">Email</label>  
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="">

      <button type="submit" name="submit" value="abschicken">Eingaben absenden</button>
    </form>
```

process.php

```
try {
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$name;charset=utf8mb4", $user, $pass);
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$connect->beginTransaction();   
if (!empty($_POST['firstform'])) {
    $alias = $_POST['name'];
    $mail = $_POST['email'];
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.document.location.href = "http://www.example.de/form2.php";</script>';
    exit;
}
if(isset($_POST['fullform'])){ 
  $connect->exec("INSERT INTO user (name, email, answer_0, answer_1, answer_2, answer_3, answer_4, answer_5, answer_6, answer_7, answer_8, answer_9, answer_10, answer_11, answer_12, answer_13, answer_14, answer_15, answer_16, answer_17) VALUES ('$alias', '$mail', '$_POST[answer_0]', '$_POST[answer_1]', '$_POST[answer_2]', '$_POST[answer_3]', '$_POST[answer_4]', '$_POST[answer_5]', '$_POST[answer_6]', '$_POST[answer_7]', '$_POST[answer_8]', '$_POST[answer_9]', '$_POST[answer_10]', '$_POST[answer_11]', '$_POST[answer_12]', '$_POST[answer_13]', '$_POST[answer_14]', '$_POST[answer_15]', '$_POST[answer_16]', '$_POST[answer_17]');");

} 
$connect->commit();
echo "Danke Für Ihre Teilnahme";
echo $_POST['email'];
exit;
```

Why is my script not redirecting after i saved the values into $alias and $mail.

Comment: change to window.location.href

Comment: try using `var_dump($_POST['firstform']);` and check if `if` condition works  according to your requirements? Do you get javascript on your page?

Comment: hmm...var_dump gives me NULL, but i dont understand why edit: if i change the if statement to if (!empty($_POST['mail'])) i get my redirect (but no value gets saved) How can firstform be null, but mail not?

Comment: Because you're using the form's name, which doesn't give anything. Only *inputs* with names will be in the POST-array.

Comment: It can be null cause you are not sending a variable named 'firstform' in your request. Modify your first form and add this variable

Comment: @Qirel ahh ok thank you,but i changed my if statement to (if (!empty($mail) || !empty($alias))) and the page is now redirecting. But my values are $alias and $mail are empty if i try to store them.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` - what does it give?

Comment: var_dump($_POST) gives me my second form (which gets saved without problems)

Comment: Well, if declare my if statement with $alias = $_POST['alias'];
        $mail = $_POST['email']; inside, my redirect doesn't work. If i declare my variables outside the if statement they don't get stored.

Comment: The HTML you showed, only has one form - and when you press submit on that, all inputs with a name will get stored in the POST-array. If you submit a new form *before* handling that input, those inputs will get overwritten. Why do you even have two separate forms, any reason you can't put them both into a singular form?

Comment: With the first form i want to get a name and an email form the visitor, after he submits them i want to store the values into variables and redirect him to  the next form. Both forms point to the same process.php. I know the post value gets overwritten, thats why i want to save them in $alias and $mail, and use them along with the values from the second form in my Insert into statement ($alias + $mail + form values are getting stored in one row inside my db)

Comment: Ah, so you're trying to save the variables, then redirect to the new script where you'll be using those variables, am I understanding you correctly? If that's what you want, that's not how it works - because once you load a new page, PHP will start from fresh, and you'll have to define those variables again. Save them in a session, and you can use them later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `header("location:http://www.example.de/form2.php");` instead of javascript.

If you want use javascript then use `window.location` instead of `window.document.location.href`

```
echo "<script type="text/javascript">window.location = 'http://www.example.de/form2.php';</script>";
```

Comment: But JavaScript is better if you need to show some text before redirect.

Answer (score 0):

On a fast search on the site, i found that and could help you.

// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect:

> window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link:

> window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";

[How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-page-redirect-using-jquery)